# Masquerading a From address in the format servername@mycompany.local in sendmail

Tags: sendmail, exchange

- Oracle Linux 5.10
- Sendmail version 8.13.8

I'm attempting to send email from a linux server to an Exchange Server and have it delivered to an external address.
Emails are currently being delivered to the exchanges server but are not being forwarded.
The exchange admin at our company tells me that I need to masquerade the From: address to be in the format of servername@mycompany.local.
I currently have the following values set in `sendmail.mc`:

```
   dnl MASQUERADE_AS(`gordmans.com')dnl
   dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(gordmans.com)dnl
```

I am still getting a ctladdr in the maillog of "servername.mycompany.net", which is the same as the output of hostname -f

How do I configure sendmail to send the right From: address?

Comment: did you configure FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope'), FEATURE(`masquerade_entire_domain', MASQUERADE_DOMAIN.. can you add more detail and also test mail output  ?

Answer (score 0):

`dnl` marks rest of the line as m4 comment

Sendmail by default masquerades only header sender addresses. Use `FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)` to masquerade envelope sender and `FEATURE(allmasquerade)` to masquerade header recipients.
[(SENDMAIL) MASQUERADING AND RELAYING](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading.html)